# Term for "Ultimate Parent" or "Ultimate Ancestor"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a term that means *ultimate parent*, in the context of the last in a line of *parent-of parent-of parent-of a subject*.  An example sentence this word or phrase would be used:

> Abraham begot Isaac, Isaac begot Jacob, Jacob begot Judah and so on, but the _____________ of all of them is Adam.

I could make something up like *ultimate ancestor* or *root ancestor*, borrowing the latter term from OS filesystem nomenclature, but I'd prefer a word that already exists for this purpose.

Answer (score 9):

I'd say the word your looking for is **primogenitor**, or possibly **progenitor**, which are seen as synonyms by Oxford Dictionary:

From https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/primogenitor

> **primogenitor** NOUN
>
> An ancestor, especially the earliest ancestor of a people; a
>   progenitor.
>
> **progenitor** NOUN
>
> 1A person or thing from which a person, animal, or plant is descended
>   or originates; an ancestor or parent. ‘his children were the
>   progenitors of many of Scotland's noble families’

I like **primogenitor** better, because it is rooted in the root **primo-**, meaning "first."

Comment: +1. The prefix *pro-* also means first, as well as "before, in front of".

Comment: @DanBron Yes, but as you said, it can mean other things as well.  That's why I favor primo-.